# Woocommerce mini cart subtotal does not update correctly after currency change

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there any JavaScript or PHP solution to recalculate and replace Subtotal of mini cart based on available price values on page reload?

Currently I have two different currencies, for example Euro & Lira, when I add some items to cart in Euro currency the subtotal is correct but when I reload page in Lira currency the Subtotal value for added items is obviously wrong, so I need to recalculate subtotal for available items on page load and replace it with the returning subtotal value by Woocommerce.

Can you please help me to do it?

---

**Update**: I tried a tweak but still does not work! By default mini-cart.php use widget hook to display total or subtotal:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total' );
```

I tried this code instead but still on page load with a different currency it does not display correct subtotal (it returns a value similar to subtoal of other currency):

```
  <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total">
        <?php
            $subtotal_txt   = isset($options['sc-subtotal-text']) ? $options['sc-subtotal-text']: __("Subtotal:",'side-cart-woocommerce');
        ?>
    <span><?php esc_attr_e($subtotal_txt,'side-cart-woocommerce') ?></span> 
    <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?>
    </p>
```

Should I add a JS or Ajax fragments to have a correct subtotal on every page load?

Comment: Please share your current code and describe where exactly it fails.

Comment: @KlausGütter  I updated it, please kindly check again.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: The important point is calling `calculate_totals()`, It seems like a bug. Anyway you may use this code instead:

```
<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total">
    <?php 
         WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
         do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total' );
    ?>
</p>
```